# Epl command file not printing properly

Tags: printing, zebra-printers, epl

I have an old model label printer TLP3742.

I have 2 files.

One for creating a stored form, and the other one sending data. (LF=Line Feed)

**form.txt**

```
(LF)
FK"*"
FS"TESTFORM"
V00,10,N,""
q464
Q152,20
S2
D8
ZT
A10,61,0,2,1,1,N,V00
FE(LF)
```

**data.txt**

```
(LF)
FR"TESTFORM"
?
HELLOWORLD
P1
```

First, I am sending **form.txt** to the printer with the command in cmd.exe as:

```
copy form.txt LPT1
```

then **data.txt** with the command:

```
copy data.txt LPT1
```

The files are successfully being copied to the printer but nothing gets printed.
Then i am sending **data.txt** again. It gets printed. Why do i have to send **data.txt** file to the printer twice?

But still there is another problem:

When i change **HELLOWORLD** to another string (I save it) and send it to the printer. it still prints **HELLOWORLD**. After that i send **data.txt** again, it prints the new string..

I couldn't find a way to get around these problems.

Comment: Shouldn't you send a ``LF`` at the end of the **data.txt**, too?

Comment: As far as I know, no need to do that.  Will that solve the problem?

Comment: I don't have a EPL printer, please try yourself